# How much of a difference does bottom-up vs top-down make in actual practice when implementing dynamic programming?

Tags: algorithms

In actual industry use, does bottom-up provide a significant speed-up compared to an equivalent top-down approach to a dynamic programming algorithm?

Assume that the top-down and bottom-up implementations both have the same asymptotic runtime.

Do the constants really make a difference? Or does this all depend on the specifics of the algorithm without any general conclusions?

Comment: Related question: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/7657/efficiency-of-forward-vs-backward-recursion-in-dynamic-programming

Comment: Hearsay: top-down approaches are usually implemented using recursion, which is a bit slower than bottom-up approaches, which are usually implemented using loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you care about such a thing depends on:

1. The specifics of the code at hand.
2. Whether the application is time-critical.

In other words, there is no general conclusion here.
Luckily, the vast majority of applications are not time-critical so we don't care.